# Show that subtraction is primitive recursive

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to show that *subtraction* is primitive recursive: $subtract(x,y)=x-y$.

To do this, I must first show that *pred* function: $pred(x)=x-1$ is also primitive recursive.

So, let's do that!

First, we start with function $f'$ that accepts two arguments and mimics *pred* function:

$f'(x,0)=g'(x)=Z(x)=0$ where $g'$ is primitive recursive by zero rule.

$f'(x,n+1)=h'(x,n,f(x,n))=\pi_2 (x,n,f(x,n))=n$ where $h'$ is primitive recursive by projection rule.

Hence, we've shown that $f'$ is primitive recursive (by recursion rule).

Then, we devise function *pred* such that: $pred(x)=f'(\pi_1 (x), \pi_1 (x))$ which is primitive recursive by composition rule (and $\pi_1 (x)$ by projection rule). Let's now see if our *pred* function works as it should:

$pred(0)=f'(\pi_1 (0), \pi_1(0))=f'(0,0)=g'(0)=Z(0)=0$ so zero case works.

And, for $n \ge 0$: $pred(n+1)=f'(\pi_1 (n+1), \pi_1(n+1))=f'(n+1,n+1)=h'(n+1,n,f(n+1,n))=\pi_2 (n+1,n,f(n+1,n))=n$

So, we have shown that *pred* function is primitive recursive. Now, let's go on to prove that *subtract* function is primitive recursive.

We can derive *subtract* function $f$ by incremental minus.

$f(x,0)=x$

$f(x,n+1)=f(x,n)-1$

Then we devise $g,h$ such that:

$g(x)=\pi_1 (x)=x$

$h(x,y,z)=pred \ (\pi_3 (x,y,z)) = pred \ z = z-1$

$g$ is primitive recursive by projection rule, and $h$ is primitive recursive by composition rule (and $\pi_3 (x,y,z)$ by projection rule).

To satisfy recursion rule:

$f(x,0)=g(x)=\pi_1 (x)=x$

$f(x,n+1)=h(x,n,f(x,n))=pred \ (\pi_3 (x,n,f(x,n)))=pred \ (f(x,n))=f(x,n)-1$

Hence, we have shown that *subtract* function is primitive recursive.

$\square$

Are the steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have noticed that you have been asking countless questions within the "lambda calculus" tag, and have not been accepting or commenting on any of the answers. Why is that?

Comment: @mell_o_tron there arn't many answers to my posts.